# Native Modules Orientation tried to override OrientationModule - no Duplicates found

Tags: react-native, android-orientation

[Native Modules tried to override Orientation Error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSsbb.jpg)

I am getting this error (on Android) when I Try to install react native orientation/orientation locker both. Based on the info in error and browsing for solutions online I found that changing the packages in MainApplication.java would help (as there would be multiple instances of this library package being created there; specifically the getPackages() method). But in my case its not so. There are no multiple entries of the same instance found in my project.

I have not edited my mainApplication.java file in any whatsoever manner. I am also attaching my mainApplication.java and mainActivity.java files to get a better overview.

Can someone please help me with this?
My react native ver is 0.63 and i haven't manually linked the library either. (I did try it though once, and throws the same error.)

```
MainApplication.java
```

```
package com.companyABC;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.sbugert.rnadmob.RNAdMobPackage;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.List;
// import from RNBranch
import io.branch.rnbranch.RNBranchModule;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost =
      new ReactNativeHost(this) {
        @Override
        public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
          return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
        }

        @Override
        protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
          @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
          List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
          // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
           packages.add(new CompanyABCPackage());
//           packages.add(new RNAdMobPackage());
          return packages;
        }

        @Override
        protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
          return "index";
        }
      };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
    RNBranchModule.getAutoInstance(this);
    initializeFlipper(this); // Remove this line if you don't want Flipper enabled
  }

  /**
   * Loads Flipper in React Native templates.
   *
   * @param context
   */
  private static void initializeFlipper(Context context) {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
      try {
        /*
         We use reflection here to pick up the class that initializes Flipper,
        since Flipper library is not available in release mode
        */
        Class<?> aClass = Class.forName("com.facebook.flipper.ReactNativeFlipper");
        aClass.getMethod("initializeFlipper", Context.class).invoke(null, context);
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
MainActivity.java
```

```
package com.companyabc;

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import org.devio.rn.splashscreen.SplashScreen;

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import io.branch.rnbranch.*;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.res.Configuration;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    SplashScreen.show(this);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  }

@Override
  public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    Intent intent = new Intent("onConfigurationChanged");
    intent.putExtra("newConfig", newConfig);
    this.sendBroadcast(intent);
  }
  /**
   * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript. This is used to schedule
   * rendering of the component.
   */
  @Override
  protected String getMainComponentName() {
    return "CompanyABC";
  }

  // Override onStart, onNewIntent:
  @Override
  protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    RNBranchModule.initSession(getIntent().getData(), this);
  }

  @Override
  public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    RNBranchModule.onNewIntent(intent);
  }
}
```

```
Package.json
```

```
{
  "name": "companyABC",
  "version": "1.0.2",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android --no-jetifier",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "postversion": "react-native-version",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.2.0",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.9.0",
    "@react-native-community/cli-platform-android": "^2.9.0",
    "@react-native-community/clipboard": "^1.2.3",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^2.6.2",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.7",
    "@react-native-firebase/admob": "^7.6.12",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^9.0.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^8.0.1",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.2.4",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.1.3",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.2.8",
    "@sentry/react-native": "^1.9.0",
    "@twotalltotems/react-native-otp-input": "^1.3.11",
    "@types/isomorphic-fetch": "^0.0.35",
    "@types/react-native-keep-awake": "^2.0.2",
    "@types/react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.8.1",
    "@types/react-native-video": "^5.0.1",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.7",
    "@types/underscore": "^1.9.4",
    "@types/uuid": "^7.0.3",
    "add": "^2.0.6",
    "bluebird": "^3.7.2",
    "date-fns": "^1.29.0",
    "graphql": "^15.3.0",
    "i18next": "^19.4.5",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "native-base": "^2.13.12",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-compound-timer": "^1.2.0",
    "react-flv-player": "^1.0.9",
    "react-i18next": "^11.5.0",
    "react-native": "^0.63.2",
    "react-native-admob": "https://github.com/vezure/react-native-admob#78356674caa5148921ff9f35f0a23eb4e29ee498",
    "react-native-agora": "^3.0.1-rc.5",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
    "react-native-branch": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-calendar-strip": "^2.0.6",
    "react-native-chart-kit": "^6.4.1",
    "react-native-countdown-circle-timer": "^2.3.10",
    "react-native-countdown-component": "^2.7.1",
    "react-native-country-picker-modal": "^1.10.0",
    "react-native-credit-card-input": "^0.4.1",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^2.4.2",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^8.3.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "^1.4.0",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "^0.14.1",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^2.3.1",
    "react-native-image-placeholder": "^1.0.14",
    "react-native-image-with-placeholder": "^0.1.1",
    "react-native-keep-awake": "^4.0.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-mo-orientation": "^0.1.10",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.5.6",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^9.0.0",
    "react-native-modalize": "^2.0.6",
    "react-native-modalize-webview": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-permissions": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-read-more-text": "^1.1.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.7.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.7.3",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.4.0",
    "react-native-simple-bottom-sheet": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-slider": "^0.11.0",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.0",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.0",
    "react-native-textinput-effects": "^0.6.1",
    "react-native-uuid": "^1.4.9",
    "react-native-video": "^4.4.5",
    "react-native-vlc-player": "^0.2.3",
    "react-native-webview": "^9.4.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0",
    "rn-orientation-view": "^1.0.3",
    "socket.io-client": "2.1.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.0",
    "timeago.js": "^4.0.2",
    "underscore": "^1.10.2",
    "uuid": "^8.0.0",
    "xendit-js-node": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.6.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
    "@types/bluebird": "^3.5.32",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.24",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.60.25",
    "@types/react-native-read-more-text": "^1.0.0",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "16.9.1",
    "@types/redux-logger": "^3.0.8",
    "@types/socket.io-client": "^1.4.32",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.12.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.12.0",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "eslint": "^7.9.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.56.0",
    "prettier": "^2.1.2",
    "react-native-version": "^4.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0",
    "typescript": "^3.7.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "node"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you find any solution? I'm getting the same error

Comment: @AndresUrdaneta yes i did find a solution to it. In my list of packages i had installed react native VLC as well. which was actually already using native module orientation. removing that vlc library solved the issue. You can use Android studio to detect what native modules are being used by a particular library